# How to write and later read IEEE 754 double in SQLLite lossless?

Tags: sqlite, ieee-754

According to [sqlite docs](https://sqlite.org/src4/doc/trunk/www/design.wiki)

> all numeric values are represented internally as an 18-digit decimal number with a 3-digit base-10 exponent.

I need to store IEEE 754 double (**including all kinds of NaN, pos/neg infinity**, etc.) and later read the same binary representation (IEEE 754 has unique representation), that is lossless. How to write and later read IEEE 754 double in SQLLite **lossless**?

Answer (score 0):

You are linking to the documentation about SQLite 4, which is in development and has no guarantees about its behaviour.

SQLite 3, the version you're actually using, stores floating-point numbers [in eight bytes, in the IEEE format](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#storageclasses).

However, NaNs are handled as NULLs, and there is no guarantees than computations on infinities are handled correctly. If you care about the binary representation, use blobs.

Comment: There are two different IEEE standards for floating-point computation. IEEE 754 (b = 2) and IEEE 854(b = 2 or b = 10). Their wiki says that "SQLite does all numeric computations using decimal arithmetic". What IEEE standard they use for **storing** float values?

Comment: The same as the CPU, i.e., b=2.